# How do I go back to wordpress 3.5

Tags: plugins

With wordpress 3.6 my getmecooking recipe plugin, now goes back to my website for each ingredient.  I have a slow internet connection.  Can I go back to 3,.5 or stop it from doing this (the recipe entry is like a blog format)

Comment: What does "goes back to my website for each ingredient" mean?

Comment: I used to enter an ingredient and then the next line would pop up and I would enter another ingredient.  Now, it goes back with the most recent ingredient line to the website, before it will pop up with the next ingredient line

Comment: Did you update the plugin? I am having a hard time thinking of a way that updating WordPress would change that behavior in a plugin.

Comment: Did not update the plugin recently

Comment: its probably some js conflict, if popup is not appearing, can you just give a check for js errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

can you restore a backup from your hosting company? it has only been a few days. most hosting companies will do a weekly restore..

if not,. you can't do a "rollback" per se,. i have done this a few times and i think this is the easiest way.

create a subdomain and install the older version 
(download the preferred version here:
http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/

once your preferred version is installed:

in the dashboard of your current install "Tools" -> "Export" 
"All content" will already be selected .. download it.

go to the new (older version) dashboard "Tools" -> "Import"
you'll be prompted to install the plugin,. once done make sure you assign the posts to either new authors or all to yourself, and check the box to import all images (i think it say media but you'll see it)

once your done remove the files and database of your old site - exept for the **wp-cotent** folder.. i keep that in case not all of the attachments came over. . extract that to the uploads folder of your new (old) install and your good.

move the site to the directory of your first install and you have effectively rolled back your wordpress website..

it is time consuming, and not suggested. 
Good luck :)